# Waking up the server at 8 am and hibernate it at 8 pm (Mon-Fri)

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, electrical-power

What is the most straightforward way to wake up the Windows Server 2008 R2 machine at 8 am and hibernate it at 8 pm (Mon-Fri)?

Thanks!

Comment: If you do this, when do you do backups?

Comment: Is this to save power, or something else?

Comment: @tony: To save power and hard drives, of course.

Comment: sounds like a good idea in those terms, people seem to be negative about this but I started to think about it and I came up with a question for myself "why did MS put hibernation into a server product if it was a bad idea to use it?". For some strange reason I think it will work fine in a small business situation!

Comment: Well if its any help its always good to know that R2 supports core parking. So if you don't have a load on the server you're unused cores should sleep. Closest thing to green next to powering it off. I guess the first time it doesn't come on at 8 a.m. though you better be near by.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most straightforward way is a scheduled task at 8 pm to do the hibernate, and set the BIOS to perform the wakeup at 8 am.

Comment: Our machine's BIOS (Dell PowerEdge T105) does not support WakeUp setting, sorry. Where can I find more info on creating a scheduled task to hibernate the machine?

Comment: @devdept Does the T105 support Wake On Lan (WOL)?

Comment: @jscott: Yes, we successfully activated WOL but with a sleep after 180 mins hibernate setting, the server does not take in account all our recent access to the machine and simple falls asleep 3 hours later even if we use it all the time. We would like the server to fall asleep after 180 mins of idle time.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have a wakeup setting in your bios then you may instead be able to enable wakeonlan and send the magic packet to wake it up from another machine.

To hibernate as a scheduled task you can download pstools from the microsoft site and use psshutdown -h http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896649.aspx

Comment: shutdown /h does hibernate, also hibernating a server is not like hibernating a desktop, it will be interesting to see what happens.

Comment: +1 - in general aterribly bad idea to even think of hibernating a server.

Comment: @EK: Is it possible that in a modern Windows 2008 R2 server I need such a tool to hibernate the machine at a specific time?

Comment: Both will work, however psshutdown pops up a message that it is going to shutdown so if you happen to be working on the machine at the time you can choose to abort it or save anything that you have open.  Also on some versions of windows there is no shutdown /h option (although there is for 2008)